# loopback remote method return variable other than request data

Tags: node.js, loopback

I have a generic SendMail route which I want to create multiple remote methods to handle multiple request templates.  Any ideas on how to return a Email_Type from the remote method back to the base route. I know I could add a default with a code in it, but would like a more elegant solution.

```
Mail.genericSendMail = function genericEmail(response, callback) {
  console.log(response);
  let templateId=0;

  //PROBLEM: HOW TO KNOW WHICH REMOTE WAS USED

   switch (response.emailType) {
     case "Template-1":
         templateId= 1234;
         break;
      case "Template-2":
         tempalteId = 456;
        break;
      default:
         templateId = 789l
      } //switch

      console.log(templateId);
};



//Want multiple routes like this to support various templates
    Mail.remoteMethod("genericEmail", {
      http: {
        path: "/emailTemplate1",  
        verb: "POST"
      },
       accepts [
         {arg: "request", type:"object",http: {source:"body"},
         default: {firstName:"", lastName:"",emailAddress:""}
      }],
      returns: RESTResponseStatic.loopbackAdapterCommonRestResponseDefinition() 

    });


//Want multiple routes like this to support various templates
Mail.remoteMethod("genericEmail", {
  http: {
    path: "/emailTemplate2",  
    verb: "POST"
  },
   accepts [
     {arg: "request", type:"object",http: {source:"body"},
     default: {emailAddress:"", promoCode:""}
  }],
  returns: RESTResponseStatic.loopbackAdapterCommonRestResponseDefinition() 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to do this. Since it happens to be a POST request, I usually go with attaching data to the body using a before remote hook.

Let's say you have a model method for logging in users.
Say we have a multi `realm` platform, so we need to know what platform we are logging in. If you don't use realms or don't know what they are, don't worry. This just shows you how to populate the data to the model method.

```
User.login = function(data, cb) {
  if (data.realm == 'platform1) {
    return logUserIntoPlatform1(data, cb);  
  }

  return logUserIntoDefaultPlatform(data, cb);
}
```

Now let's say you don't want the client/frontend to send the `realm` and you don't want to do the lookup for `realm` in the model. We can add a beforeRemote hook like so:

```
User.beforeRemote('login', function (context, user, next) {
  context.args.data.realm = lookUpRealmSync(context); // 1
  next();
});
```

This will be called before the `login` method. Note the `next()` call: this is how you could do error detection before actually hitting the model method. Something like `next({ status: 422, message: 'Parameter missing: password });` would return an error and not execute the `User.login` method.
You may have to look carefully at your context object (i.e. the line marked with 1 may not work exactly as I've shown for you).

If you want to read more about this stuff, I LoopBack's [docs](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/) are pretty good. It seems they've been updated since I've last used them so I can't link you to the more useful pages. I found the remote method documentation [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Define-a-remote-hook.html) though.

Edit: I took a closer look at your question. You should be able to retrieve the path from the `context` object and pass data accordingly. I'm not going to try to code that since I don't know where it would actually be within the object.

Comment: I was trying to stay from hooks since there would be so many possibilities.  Getting the route would be acceptable if I knew how.

Comment: As far as I know, the hook would apply to the model method and not the remote method. Meaning you could have as many remote methods as you want but just one hook. I've never tried routing multiple remote methods to one model so I cannot be sure of that though.

Comment: I'll add that loopback has a method called `getCurrentContext` (see [this](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/JA/Using+current+context)) which you could probably use to get the route. Last I used this (a year or two ago), it had nasty concurrency issues so you should check if LoopBack ever updated it.

Comment: I give up  for now.  .  Thanks for the link, I'll dig deeper this weekend.